# Dynamic height issue

Tags: html, css

I tried to implement a slideshow, but it's not fully dynamic. The image part resizes dynamically, but the navigation buttons/panels left and right as well es the overall box/frame stay the same, no matter how large the browser window.

This part of the code seems to be the issue, to be more exact, the "height" line:

```
.slides {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 840px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

I am not that good at html/css yet, but I tried various combination of setting the height and width to auto or 100%.

Here is the complete css code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

.slides {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 840px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}

.slides * {
user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: block; }

.slide {
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 100;
height: 100;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(1);

transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}


.nav label {
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: absolute;

  opacity: 0;
z-index: 9;
cursor: pointer;

transition: opacity .2s;

color: rgb(255,133,102);
font-size: 156pt;
text-align: center;
line-height: 380%;
font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
opacity: 1;

transform: scale(1);

transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;

}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
width: 100%;
bottom: 9px;
height: 11px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot {
top: -5px;
width: 11px;
height: 11px;
margin: 0 4px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 100%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
</style>
```

Anyone an idea?

Edit:

@showdev

HTML part:

```
<ul class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
<li class="slide-container" >
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/91217/pexels-photo-91217.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/91217/pexels-photo-91217.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
<li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
        <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="nav-dots">
  <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
  <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
  <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
  <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
  <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
  <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
</li>
```

Right now there are just two of the same picture linked, but the idea is that these are all the same size. I edited the code based on the other answer, forgot two percentage signs initially, and now the image is aligned with the box, but the size is only adjusting along the horizontal, not vertical axis. The result is basically a very squished image with always identically sized back and forth panes/buttons and consistent in height. This question got down-voted, not quite sure why. I have been trying to come up with a solution, I was just not successful, hence my post here.

Comment: Can we see your HTML as well? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your issue is best. Do all slides have the same aspect ratio? How exactly do you want it to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake. You have seemed to have forgotten to add a % symbol in this code here, also you should change width and height to min-width and min-height:

```
.slide {
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
width: 100;
height: 100;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(1);

transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
```

So just turn that into this:

```
.slide {
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
display: block;
position: absolute;

transform: scale(1);

transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I think it's a step in the right direction, but still doesn't solve my issue. If I include the "min-" it's back to old behavior (image dynamically resizes, box not) without them, but with the added %, the image is aligned with the box size, but it only contracts along the x (weight) axis, not the y. I added the html section to my original post.

Comment: I added the html portion to my original post, in case that helps

Comment: @FatTwin try adding "width: auto;" as one of the lines in slides, also add another line: "min-width: 100%;"